# Proving an inequality with logs and hyperbolic trig functions

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

I want to prove that there exists a constant $c\ge 0$ such that $$ln\Big(\frac{e^{\frac{\theta}{ch(\theta)}}+\frac{1}{ch^2(\theta)}\Big(sh(\theta)ch(\theta)-1\Big)}{e^{-\frac{\theta}{ch(\theta)}}+\frac{1}{ch^2(\theta)}\Big(sh(\theta)ch(\theta)+1\Big)}\Big)\ge c\theta$$

for all  $\theta>0$? 
This is what i tried to do:

The derivative of the left hand function $\frac{2sinh(\theta)cosh(\theta)}{ch^4(\theta)}(1-ch(2\theta))(\frac{2}{cosh^2(\theta)}-2cosh(\frac{\theta}{cosh(\theta)})\Big)+(cosh(\theta)+\theta sinh(\theta))(sinh(2\theta)sinh(\frac{\theta}{cosh(\theta)})+(cosh(\theta)+\theta sinh(\theta))(-2+\frac{2}{cosh^2(\theta)}cosh(\frac{\theta}{cosh(\theta)}))$

Comment: Subtract, derivate and good luck

Comment: i find a long expression can you please help me? thanks

Comment: this is what i find for the left hand function: $\frac{2sinh(\theta)cosh(\theta)}{ch^4(\theta)}(1-ch(2\theta))(\frac{2}{cosh^2(\theta)}-2cosh(\frac{\theta}{cosh(\theta)})\Big)+(cosh(\theta)+\theta sinh(\theta))(sinh(2\theta)sinh(\frac{\theta}{cosh(\theta)})+(cosh(\theta)+\theta sinh(\theta))(-2+\frac{2}{cosh^2(\theta)}cosh(\frac{\theta}{cosh(\theta)}))$

Comment: @amine: Please add all relevant information to the question itself, not to the comments. – Why do you think that such a constant exists? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: it is a question given by my professor so the costante exists

Comment: What is the function $ch$?